# Always 404 error for dynamic content in IIS on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I am trying to host a website on local IIS in Windows 7.

The version of IIS is 7.5. I have enabled every feature under IIS from Windows Feature.

My Web application is a ASP.NET MVC 5 application built in .NET 4.5.

I can host this application in my Windows 8 which is IIS 8.5.

Here is a screenshot if I visit home page of my web application.

[image]

And this is whenever I try to visit anything like `/Home/Index`

[image]

I have replicate followings as it was in my Windows 8 IIS 8.5 system.

[image]

[image]

Please help me running this site.

**UPDATE**

I just created a new MVC project in .NET 4.0 and hosted it on local IIS. It runs fine. Only applications targeting framework 4.5 not working. I have reinstalled .net framework 4.5 just to make sure that its not corrupted. But no luck. Isn't it that .NET 4.5 app can not run on IIS 7.5 in Windows 7

Comment: What user id is the application pool running as? Does it have access to the files?

Answer (score 0):

In the screen shots,  have a look at the Physical Path and make sure it is the same as your website location in the file system

Comment: Thanks @Leo but its correct. Its the same location I have put my published application